# Reading from text file and store in linked list C++

Tags: c++, linked-list, file-handling

It's been a week until I have written a code in C++ which implements a dictionary program. It reads from my "dictionary.txt" file and stores it in a linked list

My linked list node is:

```
struct node {
    string data;
    string m;
    int mcount ;
    struct node *link; 
};
```

Search() Function is

```
int search ( char *str )
{
    struct node *head = NULL ;
    node *newnode;
    string word = str;
    node *p;
    newnode = new node();
    char temp1 [ 20 ] ;
    char temp2 [ 20 ] ;
    int i ;
    ifstream n;

    //n = dic [ toupper ( str [ 0 ] ) - 65 ] ;
    n.open("dictionary.txt", ios::out);
    if(n.fail()){
        
        cout<<"\nFile not found!";
        exit(0);
    }
    strcpy ( temp2, str ) ;
    strupr ( temp2 ) ;
    head = newnode;
    while ( !n.eof() )
    {   
        getline(n, newnode->data , ' ');
        newnode->link = new node();
        newnode = newnode->link;
   }
        p = head;
        p->link=newnode;
        node *tempnode;
        tempnode = head;
        while(tempnode!=NULL){
        cout<< tempnode->data;
        tempnode = tempnode->link;
        }
```

I want it to work like this: If I  want to search a word in the dictionary.txt file, it should get its meaning from the dictionary.txt file. But it's not getting data on basis of my input, It's just getting the same output every time. In short, it's not making a search according to my input.

I have stored meanings of words like this in "dictionary.txt"

```
alive living
again repeat
against opposite
ant name of insect
```

It should search on the basis of the first word until it encounters whitespace or some special character.

Main()

```
int main() {
string word;
int i;
 cout<< "\nEnter the word to search : " ;
                fflush ( stdin );
                gets ( word ) ;
                i = search ( word ) ;
                if ( ! i )
                    cout<< "Word does not exists." ;
return 0;
}
```

Is it something I am missing or what is the error? I have read too many articles but many less or no replies match my problem.

Comment: `gets ( word ) ;` How is this `gets` defined?

Comment: Your usage of `while ( !n.eof() )` is [wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-i-e-while-stream-eof-cons). You should check if reading succeeded before using what is "read". Also note that `fflush(stdin);` [invokes *undefined behavior*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) including all of required headers and declarations.

Comment: there is no `return` in the code for `search`

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number It looks like the function `search` is not disclosed until the end (there is no `}` to indicate the end of function body) Again, a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required.

Comment: Here are the library files I am using!                                                                            #include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

Comment: Look like there is an issue in getline() function... But I am not an expert to resolve it.